# How to make bigrquery faster to retrieve data?

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I'm using "bigrquery" package on Rstudio Server to retrieve data from Google BigQuery. The target is querying 30~180 tables which are around 3.5GB individually. The query result is a table around 7~40 GB, which will be transformed into data frame in R and finally R-shiny application.

I want to know which way would be faster:

1. Using src_bigquery() + dplyr functions, and collect the data wanted at last
2. Using query_exec() to get the "raw data" first, then do all the data manipulation by dplyr

Now I am trying method 2, but I found that even the query itself only takes around 30s to run, but retrieve the query result takes more than 10 mins.

Any suggestions to accelerate this process? Or any suggestions about the comparisons between method 1 and 2?

Comment: As a general rule, you want to do as much in the database as possible before importing your data into R.

Comment: What Hong said. You should filter as much of your data through BigQuery as possible before downloading. How much data is being downloaded in each case?  It's not surprising that downloading 7-40GB of data could take more than ten minutes.

Comment: You could run the query in BigQuery (saving it in a dataset table) and then import it from R by using `list_tabledata()`.